# Angular Put Method

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm trying to do an Angular update using $http.put. The data is successfully passes from the form to the client controller when I do console.log, but when I do $http.put request. It comes back as PUT http://localhost:3000/articles 500 (Internal Server Error).

This is the client side articles.controller.js:

```
$scope.updateArticle = function(){
    var data = {
        id:         $routeParams.id, 
        title:      $scope.article.title, 
        body:       $scope.article.body, 
        category:   $scope.article.category
    }
    console.log(data);

    $http.put('/articles', data).success(function(data, status){
        console.log('abc');

    });



    $location.path('/articles');


}
```

This is the server side route for articles.js:

```
router.put('/', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.body.id;

    var data = {
        title: req.body.title, 
        category: req.body.category, 
        body: req.body.body
    };

    Article.updateArticle(id, data, function(err, article){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        res.location('/articles');
        res.redirect('/articles');
    }); 
});
```

And this is the model article.js:

```
module.exports.updateArticle = function(id, data, callback){
    var title = data.title; 
    var body = data.body; 
    var category = data.category; 

    var query = {_id: id};

    Article.findById(id, function(err, article){
        if(!article){
            return next(new Error('Could not load article'));
        } else {
            article.title = title; 
            article.body = body; 
            article.category = category; 

            article.save(callback);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You're doing a put to `/articles`, but in your route for `articles.js` I see `router.put('/'`. Do you have a `router.put('/articles')`?

Comment: `Internal Server Error` means an exception occurred in your server.  You're doing updateArticle`, Article.findById` maybe `Article` is `undefined`..?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try making a router.put route that targets "/articles" directly? Your articles.js file should look like this:

```
router.put('/articles', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Hit my route!");
    //etc... 
});
```